# Amcharts: show label at end of line when image arrive

Tags: amcharts

I've got a map image moving along a line (in a loop but only in one direction).
 I want to show the label positioned on the target point only when the map image arrives on it 
(and after tot second hiding). 
Is it possible? Is an event on what (the line or the map image)?

Comment: Likely, amCharts in general are very customizable. Have you tried https://www.amcharts.com/sign-in/?redirect_to=%2Fsupport%2F - they'll help you even if you are using the trial versions.

Comment: @Chris FYI, AmCharts support also monitors SO as well.

Comment: @Ilio - unfortunately this isn't possible. The animation events are limited to the image itself and not where it's located, so there isn't a way to detect where the image is nor what object(s) it is interacting with.

Comment: @xorspark !! I did not know that.  Thanks!